# Eigenfaces Comlex number Eigenvalues

Tags: face-recognition, complex-numbers, gsl, eigenvalue

When I calculate Covariance  (A_Transposed * A) and Calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors I always get ONE very small eigenval
Here I have 3 images in my training set.

-0.0000000242 
17221292.9979712702 
11732978.3353619855

This first unsorted eigenval is super small.
When I do SVD on these Eigenvectors I need to do eigenValues[i]^(-0.5) at some point to get the desired eigenvectors (Initial eigenvectors are smaller in length since I did (A_Transposed * A) instead of ( A * A_Transposed )).

Long storyshort, the smallest eigenval turns out to be a complex number when I do Math.pow(eval_i,-0.5). 
So do I suppose to use comlex eigensolver ?
Is such a small number normal ?
The other eigenvalues look huge, is that normal?

I have followed [this](http://jmcspot.com/Eigenface/)

Thanks

Comment: Small eigenvalues are normal.  The ratio of max to min eigenvalue is the condition number for your matrix.  A large condition number means your matrix is ill-conditioned; close to singular.  SVD can handle this, because it'll set the small eigenvalue to zero and solve on the reduced eigenspace.

Comment: Here's a response I gave to somebody else's SVD question that worked out.  See if it helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763698/solving-non-square-linear-system-with-r/19767525#19767525