# Cannot solve this matrix

Tags: r

Can someone please help? Cannot solve this matrix using R. The code is reproducible.

```
(a <- matrix(c(1, 0, 1, 0, 10, 1, 0, 0, 1, 20, 0, 1, 1, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 1, 10), nrow = 5))
(b <- matrix(c(20, 15, 10, 25, 475), nrow = 5))
solve(a) %*% b
```

Comment: Look at the error message you get: `Error in solve.default(a) : 'a' (5 x 4) must be square`

Comment: But the book has solved it using the row reduction technique. So how is it possible that it can be solved using the row reduction technique but not using R?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solving non-square linear system with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763698/solving-non-square-linear-system-with-r)

Comment: `1.` what is **THE BOOK**? `2.` Don't wrap your matrix defs in paretheses  `3.` from `?solve`  `"a - a square numeric or complex matrix containing the coefficients of the linear system. Logical matrices are coerced to numeric."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a non-square matrix. Since it has more rows than columns, you can use OLS:

```
> lm.fit(a, b)$coefficients
x1 x2 x3 x4 
 5 15  5 10
```

Alternatively you can use a generalized inverse, e.g. from MASS:

```
> MASS::ginv(a) %*% b
     [,1]
[1,]    5
[2,]   15
[3,]    5
[4,]   10
```