# Get a sample of n solutions of an under-determined system

Tags: r, equation-solving

I have a under-determined equation system (Ax = b) with infinite solutions. 
My goal is to get n random solutions (*i.e* n vectors x) for this system.
Is it possible to do it with R (if possible with base R functions) ?

With `base::qr.solve()` you can get 1 solution but it is always the same.

Here is a reproducible example to work with:

```
# Ex data illustrating this situation: Ax = b
A = matrix(
c(rep(1,11), 0.1803, 0.0071, 0.0063, 0.0201, 0.3333, 0.0043, 0.1573, 0.0007, 0.2439, 0.0072, 0.0011),
nrow = 2,
ncol = 11,
byrow = TRUE
)

b = as.matrix(c(1,0.1))

# currently not random x solutions
x = qr.solve(A, b)
```

Current result:

```
print(x)
           [,1]
 [1,] 0.5363741
 [2,] 0.4636259
 [3,] 0.0000000
 [4,] 0.0000000
 [5,] 0.0000000
 [6,] 0.0000000
 [7,] 0.0000000
 [8,] 0.0000000
 [9,] 0.0000000
[10,] 0.0000000
[11,] 0.0000000
```

Here are some related questions:

- [Solving under/overdetermined systems in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25265491/solving-under-overdetermined-systems-in-r)
- [Solving underdetermined linear systems with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53009467/solving-underdetermined-linear-systems-with-r)

Comment: oh cool my post was linked. nice. i'm honoured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the first link you provided you can get the general solution (using `MASS`):

```
library(MASS)

Ag <- ginv(A)
Ag
xb <- Ag %*% b
xb
Aw <- diag(nrow=nrow(Ag)) - Ag %*% A
Aw
```

and thus you can create n solutions in the form:

```
w <- runif(11)
z <- xb + Aw %*% w
```

like so (example matrix of 100 solutions):

```
sapply(1:100, function(i) {
  w <- runif(11)
  z <- xb + Aw %*% w}
)
```

Comment: Many thanks for this tip, I am not familiar with these functions your answer helped a lot