# Shaken faith in `qr()`

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-decomposition, qr-decomposition

I have relied on the `qr()` function a lot in dealing with rank-deficient situations, but have recently run into some examples where it doesn't work correctly. Consider the
matrix `badX` below:

```r
badX <-
structure(c(-1.641906809157e-10, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.5, 0, 0, -1.10482935525559e-16, 
            0, -3.06266685765538e-17, 0, -4.83736007092039e-17, 0, -3.14414492582296e-18, 
            -3.06158275836099e-18), dim = c(4L, 4L), dimnames = list(c("(Intercept)", 
            "A2", "A3", "B2"), NULL))
```

We cannot invert this matrix using the `solve()`:

```
solve(badX)
## Error in solve.default(badX): system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 5.55308e-18
```

Yet `qr()` and its associated routines thinks this matrix has a rank of 4 and it can invert it:

```
qr(badX)$rank
## [1] 4

qr.solve(badX)
##             [,1] [,2]          [,3]          [,4]
## [1,] -6090479645    0  2.197085e+10  7.366741e+10
## [2,]           0   -2  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
## [3,]           0    0 -3.265128e+16  3.353179e+16
## [4,]           0    0  0.000000e+00 -3.266284e+17
```

This is a pretty ugly result. I have tried varying the `tol` argument, with no change in results.

For context, the origin of this result is this contrast matrix:

```
badL <-
structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -9.89189274870351e-11, 0, -5.55111512312578e-17, 
    -2.77555756156289e-17, 1.11022302462516e-16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.25, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.25, 0, 0, 
    0, 9.89189274870351e-11, 0, 5.55111512312578e-17, 2.77555756156289e-17, 
    -1.11022302462516e-16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, -4.23939184015843e-11, 0, -4.16333634234434e-17, -1.38777878078145e-17, 
    5.55111512312578e-17, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -4.23939184015843e-11, 0, 
    -4.16333634234434e-17, -1.38777878078145e-17, 5.55111512312578e-17, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.23939184015843e-11, 0, 4.16333634234434e-17, 
    1.38777878078145e-17, -5.55111512312578e-17, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.41313127284714e-11, 
    0, -6.93889390390723e-18, -6.93889390390723e-18, 1.38777878078145e-17, 
    4.23939184015843e-11, 0, 4.16333634234434e-17, 1.38777878078145e-17, 
    -5.55111512312578e-17, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), dim = c(5L, 24L), dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("(Intercept)", "A2", "A3", "B2", "B3", "C2", "C3", 
    "A2:B2", "A3:B2", "A2:B3", "A3:B3", "A2:C2", "A3:C2", "A2:C3", 
    "A3:C3", "B2:C2", "B3:C2", "B2:C3", "B3:C3", "A2:B2:C2", 
    "A3:B2:C2", "A3:B3:C2", "A2:B2:C3", "A3:B2:C3")))
```

... from which I obtained the QR decomposition of its transpose, to find that it is supposedly of rank 4:

```
badQR <- qr(t(badL))
badQR$rank
## [1] 4
```

The above matrix `badX` is equal to `qr.R(badQR)[1:4, 1:4]` which based on the rank calculation, was supposed to be a full-rank upper-triangular matrix.

My remedy seems to be to use `zapsmall()` so that I get the rank right...

```
qr(zapsmall(t(badL)))$rank
## [1] 1
```

My question is, why does this happen? If you look at `badL`, it's pretty clear that it has three zero rows and only the second row is nonzero. I would have thought that `qr()`'s pivoting methods would work better with this. Is there a better way to get more reliable code?

I am running Windows 11 Pro, version 10.0.22000 build 22000. Here's my R system information.

```r
R.Version()
## $platform
## [1] "x86_64-w64-mingw32"
## 
## $arch
## [1] "x86_64"
## 
## $os
## [1] "mingw32"
## 
## $crt
## [1] "ucrt"
## 
## $system
## [1] "x86_64, mingw32"
## 
## $status
## [1] ""
## 
## $major
## [1] "4"
## 
## $minor
## [1] "2.0"
## 
## $year
## [1] "2022"
## 
## $month
## [1] "04"
## 
## $day
## [1] "22"
## 
## $`svn rev`
## [1] "82229"
## 
## $language
## [1] "R"
## 
## $version.string
## [1] "R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22 ucrt)"
## 
## $nickname
## [1] "Vigorous Calisthenics"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

#### More on context

This question came up because I was trying to produce results like this (for a simpler example) in the **emmeans** package:

```
> (jt = joint_tests(warpx.emm))
 model term   df1 df2 F.ratio p.value note
 tension        1  37   5.741  0.0217    e
 wool:tension   1  37   5.867  0.0204    e
 (confounded)   2  37   7.008  0.0026  d e

d: df1 reduced due to linear dependence 
e: df1 reduced due to non-estimability
```

... and in particular, the `(confounded)` part. This example is with a two-factor model with `wool` at 2 levels and `tension` at 3 levels; however, one of the factor combinations is omitted in the data, which means that we can estimate only 1 d.f. for each of the `tension` main effect and the `wool:tension` interaction effect, and no main effect at all for `wool`. There being 4 d.f. for all possible contrasts of the 5 nonempty cells, there are 2 d.f. left over, and those are in the `confounded)` part.

The computation is based on the associated estimable functions:

```
> attr(jt, "est.fcns")
$tension
     (Intercept) woolB tensionM tensionH woolB:tensionM woolB:tensionH
[1,]           0     0        1        0            0.5              0

$`wool:tension`
     (Intercept) woolB tensionM tensionH woolB:tensionM woolB:tensionH
[1,]           0     0        0        0              1              0

$`(confounded)`
     (Intercept) woolB tensionM tensionH woolB:tensionM woolB:tensionH
[1,]           0    -1        0        0              0              0
[2,]           0     1        0        0              0              0
[3,]           0    -1        0        0              0              0
[4,]           0    -1        0        1              0              0
```

... and on the contrasts among all cells in the design:

```
> contrast(warpx.emm, "consec")@linfct
     (Intercept) woolB tensionM tensionH woolB:tensionM woolB:tensionH
[1,]           0     1        0        0              0              0
[2,]           0    -1        1        0              0              0
[3,]           0     1        0        0              1              0
[4,]           0    -1       -1        1             -1              0
[5,]           0     1        0        0              0              1
```

The method I use is to combine the estimable functions for `tension` and `wool:tension`, and obtain the QR decomposition of its transpose. Then I use `qr.resid()` with that and the transpose of the above cell contrasts. That leaves us (after transposing yet again) with the estimable functions shown for `(confounded)`. That matrix has 4 rows, but its rank is only 2, as determined by the QR decomposition of this result; then I extract the 2x2 portion of the R part to complete the computation of the *F* statistic.

The example at the beginning of this question is similar, but with a larger, more complex model; the `badL` matrix is the result of the `qr.resid()` procedure described above. In this context, some of those rows arguably should be zero. My workaround at present is to examine the diagonal elements of R (`badR` in the OP) and select those that exceed an absolute threshold.

The essential idea here is that I need to decompose that matrix of all contrasts into two parts -- the known estimable functions and the leftovers. And an interesting aspect of this is that the rank of the latter part is *known*, a fact that I have not taken advantage of. In future development, it may well be, per @duffymo, to use a SVD rather than these gyrations with `qr.resid()`. There's always new stuff to learn...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are complaining that `solve` can not invert a matrix that seems to be full rank (according to `qr`). And you think that `solve` is doing the correct thing, while `qr` is not.

**Well, do not trust `solve`.** It is not a robust numerical procedure and we can fool it easily. Here is a diagonal matrix. It is certainly invertible (by simply inverting its diagonal elements), but `solve` just can't do it.

```
D <- diag(c(1, 1e-20))
#     [,1]  [,2]
#[1,]    1 0e+00
#[2,]    0 1e-20

solve(D)
#Error in solve.default(D) : 
#  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1e-20

Dinv <- diag(c(1, 1e+20))

## an identity matrix, as expected
D %*% Dinv
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    0
#[2,]    0    1

## an identity matrix, as expected
Dinv %*% D
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    0
#[2,]    0    1
```

**Now let's look at your `badX`**, which I call `R` (as it is the upper triangular matrix returned by QR factorization).

```
R <-
structure(c(-1.641906809157e-10, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.5, 0, 0, -1.10482935525559e-16, 
            0, -3.06266685765538e-17, 0, -4.83736007092039e-17, 0, -3.14414492582296e-18, 
            -3.06158275836099e-18), dim = c(4L, 4L))
```

`solve` can not invert it, but `qr.solve` gives you a proper inverse matrix.

```
Rinv <- qr.solve(R)

## an identity matrix, as expected
R %*% Rinv
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]         [,4]
#[1,]    1    0    0 1.776357e-15
#[2,]    0    1    0 0.000000e+00
#[3,]    0    0    1 0.000000e+00
#[4,]    0    0    0 1.000000e+00

## an identity matrix, as expected
Rinv %*% R
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]         [,4]
#[1,]    1    0    0 5.293956e-23
#[2,]    0    1    0 0.000000e+00
#[3,]    0    0    1 1.387779e-17
#[4,]    0    0    0 1.000000e+00
```

**QR factorization is numerically stable, by being less sensitive to the scale (or size, magnitude) of different columns.** (*Other factorizations like LU (on which `solve` is based) and SVD do.*) By definition, this factorization does

**X = Q R**

If we re-scale **X**'s columns by right multiplying a full-rank diagonal matrix **D**, the QR factorization does not change.

**X D = Q R D**

So let's look at your big matrix `t(badL)` to which you apply the QR factorization. I call it `X`.

```
X <- structure(c(0, -9.89189274870351e-11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9.89189274870351e-11, 
0, 0, 0, -4.23939184015843e-11, 0, -4.23939184015843e-11, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 4.23939184015843e-11, 0, -1.41313127284714e-11, 4.23939184015843e-11, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.25, -0.25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 
0, 0.25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -5.55111512312578e-17, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 5.55111512312578e-17, 0, 0, 0, -4.16333634234434e-17, 0, 
-4.16333634234434e-17, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.16333634234434e-17, 0, 
-6.93889390390723e-18, 4.16333634234434e-17, 0, 0, -2.77555756156289e-17, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.77555756156289e-17, 0, 0, 0, -1.38777878078145e-17, 
0, -1.38777878078145e-17, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.38777878078145e-17, 
0, -6.93889390390723e-18, 1.38777878078145e-17, 0, 0, 1.11022302462516e-16, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.11022302462516e-16, 0, 0, 0, 5.55111512312578e-17, 
0, 5.55111512312578e-17, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -5.55111512312578e-17, 
0, 1.38777878078145e-17, -5.55111512312578e-17, 0), dim = c(24L, 
5L))
```

```
#               [,1]  [,2]          [,3]          [,4]          [,5]
# [1,]  0.000000e+00  0.00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
# [2,] -9.891893e-11  0.00 -5.551115e-17 -2.775558e-17  1.110223e-16
# [3,]  0.000000e+00  0.00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
# [4,]  0.000000e+00  0.00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
# [5,]  0.000000e+00  0.00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
# [6,]  0.000000e+00 -0.25  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
# [7,]  0.000000e+00 -0.25  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
# [8,]  9.891893e-11  0.00  5.551115e-17  2.775558e-17 -1.110223e-16
# [9,]  0.000000e+00  0.00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
#[10,]  0.000000e+00  0.00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
#[11,]  0.000000e+00  0.00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
#[12,] -4.239392e-11  0.00 -4.163336e-17 -1.387779e-17  5.551115e-17
#[13,]  0.000000e+00  0.00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
#[14,] -4.239392e-11  0.00 -4.163336e-17 -1.387779e-17  5.551115e-17
#[15,]  0.000000e+00  0.00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
#[16,]  0.000000e+00  0.25  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
#[17,]  0.000000e+00  0.00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
#[18,]  0.000000e+00  0.25  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
#[19,]  0.000000e+00  0.00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
#[20,]  4.239392e-11  0.00  4.163336e-17  1.387779e-17 -5.551115e-17
#[21,]  0.000000e+00  0.00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
#[22,] -1.413131e-11  0.00 -6.938894e-18 -6.938894e-18  1.387779e-17
#[23,]  4.239392e-11  0.00  4.163336e-17  1.387779e-17 -5.551115e-17
#[24,]  0.000000e+00  0.00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
```

Let's re-scale its columns so that every column has Euclidean norm (L2 norm, 2-norm) 1.

```
norm2 <- sqrt(colSums(X ^ 2))

XD <- X * rep(1 / norm2, each = nrow(X))
```

```
#             [,1] [,2]        [,3]       [,4]        [,5]
# [1,]  0.00000000  0.0  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.00000000
# [2,] -0.60246371  0.0 -0.48418203 -0.5714286  0.57585260
# [3,]  0.00000000  0.0  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.00000000
# [4,]  0.00000000  0.0  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.00000000
# [5,]  0.00000000  0.0  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.00000000
# [6,]  0.00000000 -0.5  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.00000000
# [7,]  0.00000000 -0.5  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.00000000
# [8,]  0.60246371  0.0  0.48418203  0.5714286 -0.57585260
# [9,]  0.00000000  0.0  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.00000000
#[10,]  0.00000000  0.0  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.00000000
#[11,]  0.00000000  0.0  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.00000000
#[12,] -0.25819930  0.0 -0.36313652 -0.2857143  0.28792630
#[13,]  0.00000000  0.0  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.00000000
#[14,] -0.25819930  0.0 -0.36313652 -0.2857143  0.28792630
#[15,]  0.00000000  0.0  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.00000000
#[16,]  0.00000000  0.5  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.00000000
#[17,]  0.00000000  0.0  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.00000000
#[18,]  0.00000000  0.5  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.00000000
#[19,]  0.00000000  0.0  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.00000000
#[20,]  0.25819930  0.0  0.36313652  0.2857143 -0.28792630
#[21,]  0.00000000  0.0  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.00000000
#[22,] -0.08606647  0.0 -0.06052275 -0.1428571  0.07198158
#[23,]  0.25819930  0.0  0.36313652  0.2857143 -0.28792630
#[24,]  0.00000000  0.0  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.00000000
```

What do you think now? Is it still a matrix *with only one nonzero column*? Although `qr(X)` does not actually first re-scale all columns before QR factorization, looking at `XD` does help you better understand why QR factorization is more robust.

**If you do want to intervene, do not use `zapsmall`; threshold columns by their 2-norm, instead.**

```
X0 <- X
X0[, norm2 < max(norm2) * sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)] <- 0
QR0 <- qr(X0)

QR0$rank
# [1] 1
```

---

> How do we know that `sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)` is an appropriate threshold?

Any threshold between `sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)` (about 1e-8) and `.Machine$double.eps (about 1e-16)` is reasonable. Using `.Machine$double.eps` recovers the regular QR result, giving you rank 4.

The "sqrt" threshold comes from the situation where we want to look at `X'X`, which squares the condition number of `X`.

Comment: Thanks. The point about `solve()` is well taken, and thresholding does seem to be the most useful suggestion. But a couple of quick questions -- 1. How do we know that `sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)` is an appropriate threshold? and 2. Supposing it is, isn't that evidence that those columns of `X` are just noise? (I'm not really preferring `solve()`, I'm preferring to toss out columns that look like just noise.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you prefer [Singular Value Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition).  It will give you the best solution possible if the matrix is rank deficient.  Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763698/solving-non-square-linear-system-with-r/19767525#19767525) of how to use it in R.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it is a good fit for what I am doing, which requires that I first determine the rank of a matrix of contrasts, and then construct a test statistic based on the associated subspace.

Comment: SVD can tell you what the rank of the matrix is.

Comment: You're right. See my addition to the OP for context on what I'm really trying to do. I think I heard about SVD in 1972 or so when I was a grad student. It's something I always thought I should know more about, but you can see the persistence of my reluctance to pursue it.

Comment: Dude, it's been 50 years.  Dive in.

Comment: :-) OTOH, I've gotten by without it for that long...

Comment: @RussLenth It is easier said than done. SVD is also sensitive to the size of columns. Consider the 2 x 2 diagonal matrix in my answer. SVD, by discarding small singular values will report that the matrix has rank 1. I don't think there is a golden rule. It all depends on what you want to achieve.